# Moving wiki pages from one Confluence instance to another

Tags: confluence

We have quite a few wiki pages in `http://wiki.jira.x-y.de/`. Now we are moving to a new wiki in `http://wiki.jira.a-b.com`.

Can someone suggest what is the best way to move wiki pages from the new one to the old one (along with all the images, attachments, etc)? Do we have to manually copy paste each page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are moving the majority of the pages, the easiest way is to do a [space export](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Export+Content+to+Word%2C+PDF%2C+HTML+and+XML) from the source, and then [re-import the space](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Restoring+a+Space) on the destination site. This lets you cherry-pick just the spaces you want, and then delete the (hopefully-small) quantity of pages you do not want.

Note that you must have compatible Confluence versions to use this procedure. (See the re-import link for more details on how to determine "compatible".)

Comment: One doubt let's say I am doing a space export of `IN`. Do I have create a space `IN` on the target or I can do the import on space `XYZ` as well?

Comment: I haven't done this in a while, but IIRC the space import procedure will create a brand new space as part of the import process.

Comment: Are you saying a new space `IN` will be created under `XYZ`?

Comment: Confluence does not have a space hierarchy. Or at least not natively. I believe the space you exported from the source will be created as a new space on the client. It's been a while and many Confluence versions ago since I did this, but I don't recall even being able to change the key (i.e. it may get imported as space "IN" on the destination site too).

Comment: I feel compelled to note for the benefit of others that that might not work if there is too great a version difference between the instances. The storage format changed somewhere between v3.x and v5.x.